# moving page number anywhere on a page in Latex

Tags: latex, page-numbering

I want to print the current page number inside the defined textheight, textwidth frame on a Latex document, rather than at the page bottom. 
How can I retrieve the current page number somehow for each page and then print it inside my text region? Can I call the page number up somehow on any given page? And insert it. Not as a \label or a \cite job ?

Comment: Do you want to print it in the back-/foreground? Or as part of a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

After long fumbling along trying to get that page number to show under \pagenumber or the like, I finally hit upon \thepage. If one is on p. 48, say, and wants to display that number anywhere in the text of p. 48, one simply types \thepage to have 48 appear where it is set in the text. So simple, but it stumped me.

Why did I want that? I made the page height and page width the exact dimensions of an 8.5 by 11 page. Then - unfortunately - page numbers are automatically set below the bottom edge of the printed window of every page. And become invisible! 
Now I learnt how to print the current page number inside the visible page. Why did I use the full size of the paper? Because I was building a pdf file for a book and I wanted a seamless edges to edges picture on its front cover. Therefore the full size page width and page height ... Thanks!

\thepage, \thechapter etc was the answer. Sorry I asked.